# Is it possible to fill in derived auto-incremented id for many to one relationship?

Tags: hibernate, derived

I have two table A and B with one to many relationship. Both tables have a id field, which is auto-incremented. Table B also has a foreign key field references table A's id field.

Here is the table schema for MySQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `afield` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE B (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aId` INT NOT NULL,
  `bfield` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`aId`)REFERENCES A(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ;
```

The classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String aField;

    private List b;

    public A() {}

    public A(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "AFIELD", length = 50)
    public String getAField() {
        return this.aField;
    }

    public void setAField(String aField) {
        this.aField = aField;
    }

    //mapped by = "a" a is a field in B. Case sensetive @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "a") 
    public List getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(List b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String bField;
    private Integer id;
    private Integer aId;

    private A a;

    public B() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "aId")
    public Integer getAId() {
        return this.aId;
    }

    public void setAId(Integer aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    @Column(name = "BFIELD", length = 50)
    public String getBField() {
        return this.bField;
    }

    public void setBField(String bField) {
        this.bField = bField;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Following is my test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session sess = factory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
        A a = new A();
        a.setAField("afield");
        // sess.save(a);
        // sess.flush();

        List < B > bs = new ArrayList < B > ();
        a.setB(bs);
        B b = new B();
        b.setBField("bfield");
        // b.setAId(a.getId());
        bs.add(b);

        sess.saveOrUpdate(a);
        tx.commit();
        factory.close();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

With the commented-out three lines enabled, it works fine. Basically it gets the id from object a and set it to object b.

But I am not happy I need to save a object before save the list of b objects. Is there anyway that it would work without the three commented-out lines? The scenario is other people may just create object a and set a list object b then save object a since they don't know the detail of the relationship of the two objects and they don't know the schema as well.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please please take some time formatting your question before submitting it.

That said : The `aId` column in table B is mapped twice : once for the `aId` field, and once for `a`. This `aId` column should disappear. You should only have the association from B to A. If you want the ID of A form B, just call `b.getA().getId()`.

The other important point is that you have a bidirectional association. You should make sure that the entity graph is coherent. if you add a B to the list of Bs of an A, you must also set the A field in B :

```
a.getBs().add(b);
b.setA(a);
```

Hibernate only looks at one side of the association to know what to persist. This side is the one which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute. This means that you absolutely have to call `b.setA(a)` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am afraid I am lost. You said to make it persited I need to use b.setA(a). Actually I don't need to do that for normal situation at all. I only need to set B list in A to make both A and B persisted without problem. The problem only happen when the aId is A's primary key and it is generated natively.

Comment: Look in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional how a bidirectional one-to-many association is supposed to be mapped. The owning side is the side that Hibernate uses to decide is the association exists or not. It has to be initialized.